# Bootstrap 3 search box width can't be 100%?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I've followed their recommendation on how to put a search input (text input) in the header:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="">Foo</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Bar</a></li>
                <li><a>Qux</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="" class="form-control has-search-icon" placeholder="Bleh" style="">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

And this is what I get:

[image: Header]

But I want the searchbox to have 100% width, like this:

[image: What i want]

So I'm trying in several ways to achieve that but I can't.

Failed attempt #1:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
   <div class="form-group"> 
     <input type="text" id="" class="form-control has-search-icon"
        placeholder="Bleh" style="width: 100%"> <!-- here -->
    </div>
</form>
```

Failed attempt #2:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
   <div class="form-group" style="width:100%">  <!-- here -->
     <input type="text" id="" class="form-control has-search-icon" placeholder="Bleh" style="">
    </div>
</form>
```

etc.

The only thing that worked was fixing an absolute value to the input. Something that I don't want because it breaks the responsiveness with small screens

**How can I achieve the desired width? **

By the way: I'm using twitter's typeahead most modern version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was to tweak the CSS for form-controls and form-groups under the navbar-form:

```
.navbar-form {
    overflow: auto;
}
.navbar-form .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-form .form-group {
    display: inline;
}
```

A [Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/ROilBq6SJh) demonstrates this.

Comment: hmm if I apply twitter's typeahead to the input it puts scrolls in it

Comment: Works for me with [bootstrap3-typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead). Another [Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/VTJUlyagiP).